# Android - Remove Tab and TabFragment

Tags: android, android-tablayout

This is in activity onCreate

```
final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("A"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("B"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("C"));

final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
TabFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TabFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The Adapter

```
public class TabFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

  private int numberOfTabs;

  public TabFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            FragmentA a = new FragmentA();        
            return a;
        case 1:
            FragmentB b = new FragmentB();
            return b;
        case 2:
            FragmentA c = new FragmentC();
            return c;
        default:
            return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return numberOfTabs;

  }
}
```

I am able to remove tab using  `tabLayout.removeTabAt(1)` but how do i remove the fragment at position 1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove page from adapter as well.

Try below code:

```
public void removeTab(int position) {
    if (mTabLayout.getTabCount() >= 1 && position<mTabLayout.getTabCount()) {
      mTabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
      mPagerAdapter.removeTabPage(position);
    }
}

//This code will go in the adapter
public void removeTabPage(int position) {
      numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs - 1;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`notifyDataSetChanged();` this is very important to tell adapter we remove the item.

Comment: what is tabItems?

Comment: its your arraylist

Comment: I dont have one. Arraylist of ?

Comment: try decrease number of tabs. Try Updated Code

Comment: @Coder Does that help?

Comment: Nope. I dont think the method `removeTabPage(position)` makes any sense. Why we need to pass position? As I mentioned the tab I am removing is at position one. The code just removes tab not the fragment. Wrong fragment is shown on the last tab

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123437/discussion-between-shabbir-dhangot-and-coder).

Answer (score 0):

The only soultion that worked is to have the array list of Fragments being added in each tab and dynamically remove the tab as well as fragment.

```
private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments;

@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return fragments.get(position);
        if (position == 1)
            return fragments.get(position);
        if (position == 2)
            return fragments.get(position);
        return null;
    }

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }


    public void removeTabPage(int position) {
        if (!fragments.isEmpty() && position<fragments.size()) {
            fragments.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```